# XSLT Options for "flipping" inner and outer XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am evaluating if XSLT operations (both 1.0 and 2.0) can achieve the following conversion:

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="suiteOne">
      <testcase name="testOne" />
      <testcase name="testTwo" />
      <testcase name="testThree" />
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite name="suiteTwo">
      <testcase name="testFour" />
      <testcase name="testOne">
         <failure message="it failed">Stuff happened oh no oh geez</failure>
      </testcase>
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Converted xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite name="testOne">
      <testcase name="suiteOne" />
      <testcase name="suiteTwo">
         <failure message="it failed">Stuff happened oh no oh geez</failure>
      </testcase>
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite name="testTwo">
      <testcase name="suiteOne" />
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite name="testThree">
      <testcase name="suiteOne" />
   </testsuite>
   <testsuite name="testFour">
      <testcase name="suiteTwo" />
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Basically, I need to "swap" the inner and outer xml while maintaining the relationships. This is very doable in many languages where I can iterate through the original xml and keep track of what I've come across already (via a dictionary or something similar), but with XLST I'm not sure how trivial or complicated it may be. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I tried to format the input XML, but **This XML is invalid - some closing elements are missing**. Without properly formatted input and output XMLs - and a clear algorithm for transforming them from one to another - this question is not answerable. Read at least [HowToAsk](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [mcve] with an attempt to solve this.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. I believe I've made it valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be basically a grouping problem with a twist. Here is one way you could look at it, I think:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/testsuites">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="testsuite/testcase" group-by="@name">
            <testsuite name="{@name}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                    <testcase name="{../@name}">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    </testcase>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </testsuite>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNEj9dz/2

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have a lot to learn about what's possible with XSLT as expected :). I'll need to take the time to fully absorb this one, but it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Upon reread, I think I may have overcomplicated this. See if the simplified version works for you.